# application-test.properties not being loaded after upgrading spring boot from 2.0.0 to 2.1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

After upgrading the spring boot version from 2.0.0 to 2.1.1 the properties defined in the application-test.properties are not loaded.

The profile is properly set since the log shows this:

```
The following profiles are active: test
```

I have tried adding the below :

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```

Existing annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfiguration.class, TestMongoConfiguration.class})
```

TestConfiguration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@AutoConfigureWebClient
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories({"org.mycode"})
@DataJpaTest
@EnableMongoRepositories({"org.mycode"})
@DataMongoTest
@EntityScan(basePackages = "org.mycode")
// TODO Migration : there is a bug in spring data.
//@EnableMongoAuditing
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mycode",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = Application.class))
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

NOTE : While running the application it is able to load the properties. Looks like the trouble is only with the tests.

Comment: How do you run test? Do you have test properties or you copies properties for test?

Comment: Using mvn clean install or mvn test -Dspring.profiles,active=test or from IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes I have an application-test.properties under the src/main/resources. I tried by moving it under src/test/resources as well.